# Recaptcha not working without referring to external page

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a recaptcha form on index.php?page=signup, which get's processed on index.php?page=process-register however it always returns the recaptcha as invalid, the data is getting sent properly and I can't work out why it doesn't work. If I set the form to submit to an external page say process.php with the same contents it works just fine. Any ideas what could be causing this? I am using the reCAPTCHA PHP class written by ShevAbam (https://github.com/shevabam/recaptcha).

edit: don't know if it's worth mentioning that I use mod_rewrite to hide file extensions and run all pages such as mysite.com/index.php?page=$ as mysite.com/$/. That shouldn't have any effect, right?

Thanks in advance.

index.php?page=register

```
   if($page == 'register')
  {
echo '     

    <form action="index.php?page=process-register" method="POST">
    <h2>Register</h2>';

  echo getcaptcha();
    echo '
    <buttontype="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
 '; }
```

index.php?page=process-register

```
 if($page == 'process-register')
{ 
echo getcaptcha();
}
```

getcaptcha()

```
 function getcaptcha()
 {
     echo $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
     $reCAPTCHA = new reCAPTCHA('mykey', 'mykey');
      echo $reCAPTCHA->getScript(); 
      if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
      {

    if ($reCAPTCHA->isValid($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
        echo '<br>-- Captcha OK ! --<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'captcha not okay';
    }
       }
    else
    {
     echo $reCAPTCHA->getHtml(); 
     } 


 }
```

Comment: $reCAPTCHA->isValid($_GET.... Should probably be post.

Comment: thanks for reading, it is - just written in the post wrong as I was in the process of trying to use GET instead to see if it made any difference, it didn't. don't know if it's worth mentioning that I use mod_rewrite to hide file extensions and run all pages such as mysite.com/index.php?page=$ as mysite.com/$/. That shouldn't have any effect, right?